# How to enable gedit editor in midnight commander?

Tags: gedit, midnight-commander

How can I set `gedit` to be default editor in `mc`?

When I hit <kbd>F4</kbd>, `gedit` should be used rather than `mc`'s default editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your `EDITOR` environment variable to `gedit` and go into `mc's` options and disable the internal editor.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. 
Do you happen to know how to use gedit also for VIEWING?

Comment: How to pass options for editor? `EDITOR='rsub --port 52697'` seems does not work. MC run just editor without options ((

Answer (score 3):

As for the viewer, mc will use the one specified by the PAGER variable (“less” on my OS)

Answer (score 1):

To extend the answer by Kevin Panko and to address the comment to that answer by Eugen Konkov, I would like to share my workaround for *Midnight Commander* ignoring arguments in `$EDITOR`. Instead of passing arguments in `$EDITOR` definition directly, one can define an editor command with arguments in a script and set `$EDITOR` to that script.

For example, to ensure that each instance of *vim* has a *servername*, I use:

```
EDITOR="/path/editor-cmd.sh"

/path/editor-cmd.sh:
/usr/local/bin/vim --servername VIM "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

To use gedit as editor in midnight commander one may run:

```
editor=gedit mc
```

Internal editor has to be disabled in mc options, of course.